# Create archive on FTP in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ftp, archive, gvfs, file-roller

Trying create archive in Ubuntu 12.10 on FTP thought Nautilus right click Compress I got this message: Could not create the archive. You don't have permission to create an archive in this folder. In Ubuntu 12.04 it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

When you're ready to create the archive, do this: press `ALT-F2` and type `gksu file-roller`. Then, enter your password.
Now, use Nautilus to connect to the FTP server.

After you've connected, go back to the Archive Manager and click the "new" button. Tell it to save the file to where you need it (in the FTP directory.)
Now, open it and add the files!

If this method didn't work for you because you couldn't access the FTP directory from within the Archive Manager, then try this alternate approach:

Press `ALT-F2` and type `gksu nautilus`.
Making sure that the newly-created window is selected, choose "connect to FTP server" **from within that window**. Try what you originally were trying, but, this time, do it from within that window.

The key to both of these is to run the program as Root, incase the problem was a system permission limitation on your end. If the FTP server is rejecting write access, then there's nothing you can really do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is no mounted ftp directory in sudo file-roller and sudo nautilus. Even if it is work, it is not solution. This operation should not request sudo password. I guess it is something wrong with users permission after gvfs use /run/user/your_username/gvfs

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1077478